# Is Twisted's Deferred the same as a Promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, twisted, promise, deferred

I started using Twisted in a project that require asynchronous programming and the docs are pretty good.

So my question is, is a Deferred in Twisted the same as a Promise in Javascript? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: Actually, it goes the other way around. Twisted's deferred inspired promises in JavaScript. Not that they invented the thing, but coincidentally - one of the earliest appearances of promises in JS appeared in Dojo, added there because a Python Twisted guy missed Deferred :)

Comment: So yes, they are similar, but there are differences (for example, a Twisted deferred is both a JS promise and its resolver)

Comment: @djechlin I did and that is why I am asking here !

Comment: For what it's worth, it is a mistake (albeit a minor one) that a Deferred combines Promise and Resolver.  One day we hope to separate them within Twisted.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to your question is both **Yes** *and* **No** depending on why you're asking.

#### Yes:

Both a Twisted `Deferred` and a Javascript `Promise` implement a mechanism for queuing synchronous blocks of code to be run in a given order while being decoupled from other synchronous blocks of code.

#### No:

So Javascript's `Promise` is actually more similar to Python's `Future`, and the airy-fairy way to explain this is to talk about the `Promise` and the `Resolver` being combined to make a `Deferred`, and to state that this affects what you can do with the callbacks.

This is all very well and good in that it's accurate, however it doesn't really make anything any clearer, and without typing thousands of words where I'm almost guaranteed to make a mistake, I'm probably better quoting someone who knows a little something about Python.

> [Guido van Rossum on Deferreds](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tulip/ut4vTG-08k8/discussion):
>
> Here's my attempt to explain Deferred's big ideas (and there are a lot
>   of them) to advanced Python users with no previous Twisted experience.
>   I also assume you have thought about asynchronous calls before. Just
>   to annoy Glyph, I am using a 5-star system to indicate the importance
>   of ideas, where 1 star is "good idea but pretty obvious" and 5 stars
>   is "brilliant".
>
> I am showing a lot of code snippets, because some ideas are just best
>   expressed that way -- but I intentionally leave out lots of details,
>   and sometimes I show code that has bugs, if fixing them would reduce
>   understanding the idea behind the code. (I will point out such bugs.)
>   I am using Python 3.
>
> Notes specifically for Glyph: (a) Consider this a draft for a blog
>   post. I'd be more than happy to take corrections and suggestions for
>   improvements. (b) This does not mean I am going to change Tulip to a
>   more Deferred-like model; but that's for a different thread.
>
> Idea 1: Return a special object instead of taking a callback argument
>
> When designing APIs that produce results asynchronously, you find that
>   you need a system for callbacks. Usually the first design that comes
>   to mind is to pass in a callback function that will be called when the
>   async operation is complete. I've even seen designs where if you don't
>   pass in a callback the operation is synchronous -- that's bad enough
>   I'd give it zero stars. But even the one-star version pollutes all
>   APIs with extra arguments that have to be passed around tediously.
>   Twisted's first big idea then is that it's better to return a special
>   object to which the caller can add a callback after receiving it. I
>   give this three stars because from it sprout so many of the other good
>   ideas. It is of course similar to the idea underlying the Futures and
>   Promises found in many languages and libraries, e.g. Python's
>   concurrent.futures (PEP 3148, closely following Java Futures, both of
>   which are meant for a threaded world) and now Tulip (PEP 3156, using a
>   similar design adapted for thread-less async operation).
>
> Idea 2: Pass results from callback to callback
>
> I think it's best to show some code first:
>
> ```
> class Deferred:
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.callbacks = []
>     def addCallback(self, callback):
>         self.callbacks.append(callback)  # Bug here
>     def callback(self, result):
>         for cb in self.callbacks:
>             result = cb(result)
> ```
>
> The most interesting bits are the last two lines: the result of each
>   callback is passed to the next. This is different from how things work
>   in concurrent.futures and Tulip, where the result (once set) is fixed
>   as an attribute of the Future. Here the result can be modified by each
>   callback.
>
> This enables a new pattern when one function returning a Deferred
>   calls another one and transforms its result, and this is what earns
>   this idea three stars. For example, suppose we have an async function
>   that reads a set of bookmarks, and we want to write an async function
>   that calls this and then sorts the bookmarks. Instead of inventing a
>   mechanism whereby one async function can wait for another (which we
>   will do later anyway :-), the second async function can simply add a
>   new callback to the Deferred returned by the first one:
>
> ```
> def read_bookmarks_sorted():
>     d = read_bookmarks()
>     d.addCallback(sorted)
>     return d
> ```
>
> The Deferred returned by this function represents a sorted list of
>   bookmarks. If its caller wants to print those bookmarks, it must add
>   another callback:
>
> ```
> d = read_bookmarks_sorted()
> d.addCallback(print)
> ```
>
> In a world where async results are represented by Futures, this same
>   example would require two separate Futures: one returned by
>   read_bookmarks() representing the unsorted list, and a separate Future
>   returned by read_bookmarks_sorted() representing the sorted list.
>
> There is one non-obvious bug in this version of the class: if
>   addCallback() is called after the Deferred has already fired (i.e. its
>   callback() method was called) then the callback added by addCallback()
>   will never be called. It's easy enough to fix this, but tedious, and
>   you can look it up in the Twisted source code. I'll carry this bug
>   through successive examples -- just pretend that you live in a world
>   where the result is never ready too soon. There are other problems
>   with this design too, but I'd rather call the solutions improvements
>   than bugfixes.
>
> Aside: Twisted's poor choices of terminology
>
> I don't know why, but, starting with the project's own name, Twisted
>   often rubs me the wrong way with its choice of names for things. For
>   example, I really like the guideline that class names should be nouns.
>   But 'Deferred' is an adjective, and not just any adjective, it's a
>   verb's past participle (and an overly long one at that :-). And why is
>   it in a module named twisted.internet?
>
> Then there is 'callback', which is used for two related but distinct
>   purposes: it is the preferred term used for a function that will be
>   called when a result is ready, but it is also the name of the method
>   you call to "fire" the Deferred, i.e. set the (initial) result.
>
> Don't get me started on the neologism/portmanteau that is 'errback',
>   which leads us to...
>
> Idea 3: Integrated error handling
>
> This idea gets only two stars (which I'm sure will disappoint many
>   Twisted fans) because it confused me a lot. I've also noted that the
>   Twisted docs have some trouble explaining how it works -- In this case
>   particularly I found that reading the code was more helpful than the
>   docs.
>
> The basic idea is simple enough: what if the promise of firing the
>   Deferred with a result can't be fulfilled? When we write
>
> ```
> d = pod_bay_doors.open()
> d.addCallback(lambda _: pod.launch())
> ```
>
> how is HAL 9000 supposed to say "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't
>   do that" ?
>
> And even if we don't care for that answer, what should we do if one of
>   the callbacks raises an exception?
>
> Twisted's solution is to bifurcate each callback into a callback and
>   an 'errback'. But that's not all -- in order to deal with exceptions
>   raised by callbacks, it also introduces a new class, 'Failure'. I'd
>   actually like to introduce the latter first, without introducing
>   errbacks:
>
> ```
> class Failure:
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.exception = sys.exc_info()[1]
> ```
>
> (By the way, great class name. And I mean this, I'm not being
>   sarcastic.)
>
> Now we can rewrite the callback() method as follows:
>
> ```
> def callback(self, result):
>     for cb in self.callbacks:
>         try:
>             result = cb(result)
>         except:
>             result = Failure()
> ```
>
> This in itself I'd give two stars; the callback can use
>   isinstance(result, Failure) to tell regular results apart from
>   failures.
>
> By the way, in Python 3 it might be possible to do away with the
>   separate Failure class encapsulating exceptions, and just use the
>   built-in BaseException class. From reading the comments in the code,
>   Twisted's Failure class mostly exists so that it can hold all the
>   information returned by sys.exc_info(), i.e. exception class/type,
>   exception instance, and traceback but in Python 3, exception objects
>   already hold a reference to the traceback.There is some debug stuff
>   that Twisted's Failure class does which standard exceptions don't, but
>   still, I think most reasons for introducing a separate class have been
>   addressed.
>
> But let's not forget about the errbacks. We change the list of
>   callbacks to a list of pairs of callback functions, and we rewrite the
>   callback() method again, as follows:
>
> ```
> def callback(self, result):
>     for (cb, eb) in self.callbacks:
>         if isinstance(result, Failure):
>             cb = eb  # Use errback
>         try:
>             result = cb(result)
>         except:
>             result = Failure()
> ```
>
> For convenience we also add an errback() method:
>
> ```
> def errback(self, fail=None):
>     if fail is None:
>         fail = Failure()
>     self.callback(fail)
> ```
>
> (The real errback() function has a few more special cases, it can be
>   called with either an exception or a Failure as argument, and the
>   Failure class takes an optional exception argument to prevent it from
>   using sys.exc_info(). But none of that is essential and it makes the
>   code snippets more complicated.)
>
> In order to ensure that self.callbacks is a list of pairs we must also
>   update addCallback() (it still doesn't work right when called after
>   the Deferred has fired):
>
> ```
> def addCallback(self, callback, errback=None):
>     if errback is None:
>         errback = lambda r: r
>     self.callbacks.append((callback, errback))
> ```
>
> If this is called with just a callback function, the errback will be a
>   dummy that passes the result (i.e. a Failure instance) through
>   unchanged. This preserves the error condition for a subsequent error
>   handler. To make it easy to add an error handler without also handling
>   a regular resullt, we add addErrback(), as follows:
>
> ```
> def addErrback(self, errback):
>     self.addCallback(lambda r: r, errback)
> ```
>
> Here, the callback half of the pair will pass the (non-Failure) result
>   through unchanged to the next callback.
>
> If you want the full motivation, read Twisted's Introduction to
>   Deferreds; I'll just end by noting that an errback and substitute a
>   regular result for a Failure just by returning a non-Failure value
>   (including None).
>
> Before I move on to the next idea, let me point out that there are
>   more niceties in the real Deferred class. For example, you can specify
>   additional arguments to be passed to the callback and errback. But in
>   a pinch you can do this with lambdas, so I'm leaving it out, because
>   the extra code for doing the administration doesn't elucidate the
>   basic ideas.
>
> Idea 4: Chaining Deferreds
>
> This is a five-star idea! Sometimes it really is necessary for a
>   callback to wait for an additional async event before it can produce
>   the desired result. For example, suppose we have two basic async
>   operations, read_bookmarks() and sync_bookmarks(), and we want a
>   combined operation. If this was synchronous code, we could write:
>
> ```
> def sync_and_read_bookmarks():
>     sync_bookmarks()
>     return read_bookmarks()
> ```
>
> But how do we write this if all operations return Deferreds? With the
>   idea of chaining, we can do it as follows:
>
> ```
> def sync_and_read_bookmarks():
>     d = sync_bookmarks()
>     d.addCallback(lambda unused_result: read_bookmarks())
>     return d
> ```
>
> The lambda is needed because all callbacks are called with a result
>   value, but read_bookmarks() takes no arguments.