# Using `concurrent.futures.Future` as promise

Tags: python, concurrency, promise, future, concurrent.futures

In the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) I see:

> `concurrent.futures.Future`... ...should not be created directly
>   except for testing.

And I want to use it as a promise in my code and I'm very surprised that it is not recommended to use it like this.

My use case:
I have a *single* thread that reads data packets coming from socket, and I have *many* callbacks that are called depending on some information contained in packets. Packets are responses to consumers requests, and all consumers use single connection. Each consumer receives a promise and adds some handlers to it, that are invoked when response arrives.

So I cant use `Executor` subclass here, because I have only one thread, but I need to create many Futures (promises).

Promise is pretty widespread programming technique and, I thought that `Future` is Python's promise implementation. But if it is not recommended to use it like promise, what pythonistas are commonly use for this purpose?

### Note

I use  Python 2.7 [backport of `concurrent.futures` to 2.7](https://pythonhosted.org/futures/)

Comment: The Executor class does not even implement creating futures - subclasses do. I just used the Future class. There was no problem with this. Maybe the author knows why this is written there.

Comment: @User I meant subclass. I think I will just use them too. p.s. Cool nickname.

Answer (score 8):

It's perfectly *fine* to use `Future` in order to wrap non-promise APIs into promises.

The reason it *generally* should not be created is because most times people create futures directly it's because they're [doing the deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and wrapping an executor created future in another future.

It's worth mentioning that this future implementation is *very weak*, it's akin to Java's old futures, the cool stuff promises give you like chaining is simply missing. It's worth mentioning that languages like JavaScript [got their promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375321/is-twisteds-deferred-same-as-promise-in-javascript) from Python's Twisted, which has a better implementation, even if it's intertwined with other things.

Comment: What can you say about the docs? [_"should not be created directly except for testing"_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) or [_"should only be used by Executor implementations and unit tests"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.set_result) - these are very precise statements, they are explicitly say, where `Future` should created directly and prohibit everything else.

Comment: Re: "cool stuff promises give you like chaining is simply missing" - that annoyed me greatly, so put together `concurrent.futures.Future` extended to support Promises/A+ `.then(success, error)` API (https://github.com/dvdotsenko/python-future-then)

Comment: "Python's Twisted, which has a better implementation": you mean Twisted implementation is better compared to `concurrent.futures`, not compared to to JavaScript, right? I was under the impression that a Promises/A+ compliant implementation is superior to Twisted - and IIUC by now all popular JavaScript implementations include Promise/A+ compliance plus some helpful extras.

Comment: @max you understand correctly - although modern Python has better futures now anyway.